# Making a response for sending a datagram via udp socket

Tags: udp

So I have a program that sends datagram to a UDP port (let's call it left) and a program that receives this datagram (let's call it right).
Is there any way to send a datagram with a response, from "right" to "left" (using the same UDP port is an option, but two ports is prohibited)?

Comment: The answer to your question is 'Yes'. You'll need to describe the problems you are having.

Comment: @Amartel
Well I tried binding and "rebinding", using ".abort" or ".close" and that just didn't work for me.
Then I had an idea, that there is some kind of a function, that returns the senders address (port to be exact), that can be converted to some usable value and used in ".bind" or ".writeDatagram"

Comment: You need to bind port on both sides in order to exchange data. If you want to use several sockets on one port of single computer, you'll have to change [bind mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qabstractsocket.html#BindFlag-enum).

Comment: @Amartel
Tried to use various bind modes, but the result is still the same - "left" sends  datagram to himself and "right" doesn't even take part in process

Comment: I usually use `QUdpSocket::ShareAddress | QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint` (one for windows, one for linux). Without seeing you code, can't help with anything else.